# C++ call overridden method

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

Lets say I have a an interface-like base class

```
struct service_base {
  
  virtual ~service_base() = default;

  virtual void initialize() = 0;
  
};
```

and then I implement is using the following class

```
template<Derived>
class system : public system_base {

  using derived_type = Derived;

public:

  virtual ~system() = default;

  virtual initialize() override {
    // How can I call the derived initialize here?

    // set some internal state after derived initialize has been called
  }

};
```

And the at the end I would like to derive from `system` like

```
class my_system final : public system<my_system> {

public:
 
  ~my_system() = default;

  // how do I implement this that the user can implement some cusom behavior here without
  // having to worry about the base class ?
  void initialize() override {

  }

};
```

So basically I want that the users code inside his `void initialize()` get called first and then I want to manage some internal state of the system.

I then want to store all system implementations inside a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<system_base>>`. Thats why I need the interface.

Is this even possible? Are the alternative patterns I could use for this kind of functionality?

Comment: It sounds like you want `system<T>` to define a *new* (potentially abstract) function, say `initialize_system`, which is called from the `system_base::initialize` method. Reusing the base method for this kind of trickery is dubious.

Comment: why not simply call `system<T>::initialize` inside `my_system::initialize`?

Comment: also when and how `system<T>::initialize` is invoked?

Comment: You are mixing 2 alternative mechanisms that typically should not be used together: dynamic polymorphism (i.e., virtual functions) and CRTP.